is there a way to do this kind of computation where columns are interdependent with numpy.where without for loop
I have a small df with one column, z_score. I'll then create 3 columns - sell, position, and short_exit.
enter image description here
                     z_score
2024-05-23 21:00:00  0.639482
2024-05-23 22:00:00  1.133366
2024-05-23 23:00:00 -0.267677
2024-05-24 00:00:00  0.681130
2024-05-24 01:00:00  2.283615
2024-05-24 02:00:00  1.916469
2024-05-24 03:00:00  2.284099
2024-05-24 04:00:00  2.283456
2024-05-24 05:00:00  2.699485
2024-05-24 06:00:00  2.393399
2024-05-24 07:00:00  1.871835
2024-05-24 08:00:00  1.824887

The trading rule is that if z_score is greater than 2 AND there's no an open position, sell. Which means sell value in that row will become 1. The position, with the default value of 0, also becomes 1 (this means I have an open position). It remains 1 until the position is closed. When z_score falls below 0, the position is closed, i.e., position becomes 0 again. In that case, short_exit gets the value of 1, and the position becomes 0 again because we don't have an open position.
I believe it's not that hard to do it. But I somehow failed.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel("gate.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet3")
# Assuming your data is in a DataFrame called df
# Initialize sell and positions columns with zeros
df['sell'] = 0
df['positions'] = 0
df['short_exit'] = 0

df['sell'] = np.where((df['z_score'] > 2) & (df['positions'].shift(1) == 0), 1, 0)
df['positions'] = np.where(((df['sell'] == 1) | (df['positions'].shift(1) == 1)) & (df['short_exit'] == 0), 1, df['positions'])
df['short_exit'] = np.where((df['z_score'] < 0) & (df['positions'] == 1), 1 ,0)



# Display the resulting DataFrame
print(df)


The expected result should be like in the attached image. In what I get position column gets value of 0 in some rows in which it shouldn't.
enter image description here
Any help or hint is appreciated.
By the way is it possible to do it numpy? In one forum I was told that it requires recursion so isn't possible to do it like I want to solve it.

can you provide what your input looks like?

Please don't upload data as an image. See here on how to write a good pandas question.

This is not a candidate for parallelization.  In fact, it's not clear that pandas helps you at all.  Each row depends on the RESULT of all previous rows, not just the value.  You need to do this in a loop.

I added input data sample, thank you for your comments.

The where is only as good as the condition result - here a boolean series that is evaluated for all rows at once, The arguments are evaluated in full before being passed to where.

IIUC, you can create 2 conditions to open and close the positions and compute the "positions" column by forward filling the intermediates, then sell/short_exit should be derived from that:
m1 = df['z_score'].gt(2)
m2 = df['z_score'].lt(0)

df['positions'] = m1.where(m1|m2).ffill().fillna(False)
df['sell'] = df['positions'] & df['positions'].diff()
df['short_exit'] = m2 & df['positions'].shift()

df[['positions', 'sell', 'short_exit']] = df[['positions', 'sell', 'short_exit']].astype(int)

Output (with an extra row to demonstrate the short exit):
                      z_score  positions  sell  short_exit
2024-05-23 21:00:00  0.639482          0     0           0
2024-05-23 22:00:00  1.133366          0     0           0
2024-05-23 23:00:00 -0.267677          0     0           0
2024-05-24 00:00:00  0.681130          0     0           0
2024-05-24 01:00:00  2.283615          1     1           0
2024-05-24 02:00:00  1.916469          1     0           0
2024-05-24 03:00:00  2.284099          1     0           0
2024-05-24 04:00:00  2.283456          1     0           0
2024-05-24 05:00:00  2.699485          1     0           0
2024-05-24 06:00:00  2.393399          1     0           0
2024-05-24 07:00:00  1.871835          1     0           0
2024-05-24 08:00:00  1.824887          1     0           0
2024-05-24 09:00:00 -0.123456          0     0           1


Thank you! I think this is what I need. Could you please advise what these three lines do?df['positions'] = m1.where(m1|m2).ffill().fillna(False)
df['sell'] = df['positions'] & df['positions'].diff()
df['short_exit'] = m2 & df['positions'].shift()

More concise way :
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

score = np.array([0.639482, 1.133366, -0.267677, 0.681130, 2.283615, 1.916469, 2.284099,
                    2.283456, 2.699485, 2.393399, 1.871835, 1.824887, -0.123456])
index = pd.to_datetime([
    "1990-05-23 21:00:00", "1990-05-23 22:00:00", "1990-05-23 23:00:00", "1990-05-24 00:00:00",
    "1990-05-24 01:00:00", "1990-05-24 02:00:00", "1990-05-24 03:00:00", "1990-05-24 04:00:00",
    "1990-05-24 05:00:00", "1990-05-24 06:00:00", "1990-05-24 07:00:00", "1990-05-24 08:00:00",
    "1990-05-24 09:00:00"
])

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'score': score}, index=index)
print(df)

positions = np.cumsum(score > 2) > 0
positions &= ~(score < 0)
df['positions'] = positions.astype(int)
sell = (df['positions'].shift(1) == 0) & (df['score'] > 2)
df['sell'] = sell.astype(int)
short_exit = (df['score'] < 0) & (df['positions'].shift(1) == 1)
df['short_exit'] = short_exit.astype(int)

print(df)
'''
                        score  positions  sell  short_exit
1990-05-23 21:00:00  0.639482          0     0           0
1990-05-23 22:00:00  1.133366          0     0           0
1990-05-23 23:00:00 -0.267677          0     0           0
1990-05-24 00:00:00  0.681130          0     0           0
1990-05-24 01:00:00  2.283615          1     1           0
1990-05-24 02:00:00  1.916469          1     0           0
1990-05-24 03:00:00  2.284099          1     0           0
1990-05-24 04:00:00  2.283456          1     0           0
1990-05-24 05:00:00  2.699485          1     0           0
1990-05-24 06:00:00  2.393399          1     0           0
1990-05-24 07:00:00  1.871835          1     0           0
1990-05-24 08:00:00  1.824887          1     0           0
1990-05-24 09:00:00 -0.123456          0     0           1
'''

method 2 :
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


z_score = np.array([0.639482, 1.133366, -0.267677, 0.681130, 2.283615, 1.916469, 2.284099,
                    2.283456, 2.699485, 2.393399, 1.871835, 1.824887, -0.123456])
index = pd.to_datetime([
    "2024-05-23 21:00:00", "2024-05-23 22:00:00", "2024-05-23 23:00:00", "2024-05-24 00:00:00",
    "2024-05-24 01:00:00", "2024-05-24 02:00:00", "2024-05-24 03:00:00", "2024-05-24 04:00:00",
    "2024-05-24 05:00:00", "2024-05-24 06:00:00", "2024-05-24 07:00:00", "2024-05-24 08:00:00",
    "2024-05-24 09:00:00"
])

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'z_score': z_score}, index=index)

m1 = z_score > 2 
m2 = z_score < 0
 
positions = np.zeros_like(z_score,dtype =bool)
positions[m1] = True
for i in range(1,len(positions)):
    if positions[i-1] : 
        positions[i] = True
    if m2[i] : 
        positions[i] = False
        

df['positions'] = positions.astype(int)

sell = np.zeros_like(z_score,dtype=bool)
sell[1:] = positions[1:] & ~positions[:-1]
#Or sell[1:] = m1[1:] & ~positions[:-1]
sell = sell.astype(int)
df['sell'] = sell

short_exit = np.zeros_like(z_score,dtype=bool)
short_exit[1:] = m2[1:] & positions[:-1]
short_exit = short_exit.astype(int)
df['short_exit'] = short_exit

print(df)
'''
                     z_score  positions  sell  short_exit
2024-05-23 21:00:00  0.639482          0     0           0
2024-05-23 22:00:00  1.133366          0     0           0
2024-05-23 23:00:00 -0.267677          0     0           0
2024-05-24 00:00:00  0.681130          0     0           0
2024-05-24 01:00:00  2.283615          1     1           0
2024-05-24 02:00:00  1.916469          1     0           0
2024-05-24 03:00:00  2.284099          1     0           0
2024-05-24 04:00:00  2.283456          1     0           0
2024-05-24 05:00:00  2.699485          1     0           0
2024-05-24 06:00:00  2.393399          1     0           0
2024-05-24 07:00:00  1.871835          1     0           0
2024-05-24 08:00:00  1.824887          1     0           0
2024-05-24 09:00:00 -0.123456          0     0           1

'''


if you to add to this if m1[0]:     sell[0] = 1, this fixes the issue. Because in its original form, even if the first row is over 2, sell signal is not generated.
